# Ruby on rails error "can't modify frozen Array" when installing refinery CMS as engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I have a ruby on rails application that is working fine, now I'm trying to install refinerycms http://refinerycms.com/ as engine in my application, following this advise https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2887

However I'm getting an error "can't modify frozen Array", and its source is `MyApp::Application.initialize!`  in environment.rb file.

Any clue ? This is the stack trace

```
/home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `push': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `use'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/xray-rails-0.1.15/lib/xray/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    from /home/badrit/work/seeloz_mobile_backend/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/badrit/work/seeloz_mobile_backend/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/badrit/work/seeloz_mobile_backend/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/badrit/work/seeloz_mobile_backend/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/badrit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You would probably want to look at the full stack trace of the error (and include it in your question). That way, we could see which particular line it is that attempts the array modification.

Comment: I added the stack trace now

Comment: could u find the answer for this?

Comment: @mariomol, no unfortunately